# Invoking Constructor using reflection produces NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Given class Award :

```
public class Award {


    /*
     * 
     */

    // fields of the class 

    Award()
    {
        // some initializations


    }
```

I'm trying to invoke this constructor from Main :

```
    try
    {
        Award myAward = Award.class.getConstructor().newInstance();
        myAward.calculateAward(); 
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it goes into the exception block and produces NoSuchMethodException exception .

What's wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you create an instance of a method ?

Comment: @Satya: If I do this "Award a = new Award();" then the code works .

Comment: the line Award a = new Award(); is creating an object of the class Award .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is your constructor is not `public` so you will need to use `getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();` or make the constructor `public`.

Comment: or just use dp4j's '@Reflect' annotation (and it will generate Krroae's code for you) or make it public (if you can) and document that with Google's '@PublicForTesting' annotation.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29):

> The constructor to reflect is the public constructor of the class represented by this Class object whose formal parameter types match those specified by parameterTypes.

You constructor may need to be public. Add the `public` keyword before your `Award` constructor and try again.